# debian interactive shell does not call .profile

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have just installed a brand new debian buster:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

```
$ cat /etc/profile
 [..]
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

[...]
```

```
$ whoami 
zozo
$ su 
Password:
# id -u 
0
# printenv | grep -i ^path 
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

If I run as root:

- `# grep -i path /etc/profile.d/*`
  no output
- `# grep -i path ~/.profile`
  no output
- `# grep -i path ~/.bashrc`
  no output

Being on a Debian system there is no `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login`

```
vi ~/.profile 
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

but the problem remains:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get back to normal user

then

```
$ su 
password: 

# printenv | grep -i ^path
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

So I made some searches: [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

then

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ];then echo NOT interactive shell ;else echo INteractive shell ;fi
INteractive shell
```

it says:

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, [...] it first reads and executes [...] /etc/profile [...]. After [...] it looks for [...] ~/.profile ...

So I am wondering why it does not load `PATH` from `~/.profile` (`~/.profile` is not called/loaded). Of course, if I put it in `~/.bashrc`, it works.

So, at the end, by default, no path for essential commands like shutdown or reboot.

Furthermore, I am realizing that tools like `systemctl`, which are by essence an administration commands are located in `/usr/bin` instead of `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`  (and many other admin commands, like `getfacl`, `setfacl`... but that's another problem).

I should have missed something here.

Comment: What does `echo $0` print?

Comment: @schily: $0 prints 'bash'

Comment: Then this is not a login shell and this is the reason.

Comment: The one in your desktop environment's terminal emulator is most likely a non-login shell (which doesn't source `~/.profile`). Usually, the display manager takes care of setting up the environment for each graphical user session. E.g. I see on a fresh buster VM that gdm3 (GNOME display manager) runs a login shell (and thus sources `~/.profile`) to `exec` the GNOME Session Manager. Changes to `~/.profile` require you to log out/in to be visible, but should also take effect immediately in a login shell (i.e. invoked as `bash -l`). (Cont...)

Comment: (...Cont) If this is not the case, please also add the desktop environment, display manager and terminal emulator you are using to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only a login shell reads `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`.

You may check this by calling `echo $0`.

If the output starts with a minus sign (e.g. `-bosh`), this is a login shell.

So a good idea is to log out and log in again after you changed `/etc/profile`

Files like `/etc/sh.shrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` or their counterparts in $HOME are read by **any** interactive shell, not only by the login shell.

Since your shell is not a login shell, you should try to find out why this happens. If you log in via `ssh` or from a text console and your shell is not marked as a login shell, you definitely should make a bug report against your distro.

A correct X11 environment starts all shells in newly created shell windows with `argv[0]` beginning with `-` and for this reason, such shells identify themselves as login shell. If this does not happen for you, your X11 environment may be broken.

If you start a super-user session with `su`, this definitely does not start a login shell. If you like such a shell to behave like a login shell, call:

```
su -
```

Did you try that?

Comment: -@schily:no matters what I do, it never works unless I define PATH in ~/.bashrc or I source ~./profile.

Comment: I again enhanced my answer..